# how can ı monitor emotiv epoc headset eeg data on python

Tags: python, json, websocket

I need to watch the emotiv epoc EEG signals without emotiv licence ,ı saw something named cortex API when ı tried the same thing in this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKvhDe7tNts&t=163s" but ı got " no module named websocket" error but ı already installed websocket. I really need your help. how can ı monitoring EPOC header eeg signals in real time on python ??
and sorry for my english

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put all the relevant information into your question instead of referring to an external source. If you expect people to watch a video to try to understand your problem, you make it extra hard (and highly unlikely) for people to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.